# How to fix "RenderObject infinite size" layout error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I'm encountering the following error in my Flutter layout:

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================  The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderPhysicalModel
> object was given an infinite size during layout.
>
> This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that
> allows its children to pick their own size. The nearest ancestor
> providing an unbounded height constraint is:
>
> _RenderSingleChildViewport#4c3d2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE ...  needs compositing ...  parentData:
>  (can use size) ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=1366.0,
> h=657.0) ...  size: MISSING ...  offset: Offset(0.0, -0.0) The
> constraints that applied to the RenderPhysicalModel were:
> BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=1366.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity) The exact size it was
> given was: Size(1366.0, Infinity)

**Code:**

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            child: Scrollbar(
              thumbVisibility: true,
              controller: _firstController,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _firstController,
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                      height: constraints.maxHeight, 
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: DefaultTabController(
                         /// code...
                      ));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

**Explanation:** The error message indicates an infinite height issue within my layout.  I'd like to understand how to resolve this and prevent similar issues in the future.

**What I've tried:**

- I've researched common causes of this error, but I'm still unable to pinpoint the reason within my code.

**Request:** Could you please help identify the problematic part and suggest solutions?

**Thank you!**

Comment: Can you simplify the widget that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove width : double.infinity

It will try to create a container of infinite width which will work if the parent widget has bounds